# Adding flat_ui to rails app - followed instructions but page throws errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

current setup

**GemFile**

```
#More stuff above
gem "flatui-rails"
```

**application.css**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require flat_ui
 */
```

When I try to load the page in development mode I get the error
*couldn't find file 'flat_iu'*

I have already run bundle

bundle show flat_ui
result: ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/flatui-rails-0.0.4

I can't figure out what I am missing at this point. This is my first rails app so I don't know if there is something I am leaving out above.

**Environment**

- rails version 4 - development server
- ruby version 2.0.0p247
- Linux (elementary os)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have misspelled the library's name. It's a dash rather than an underscore.

```
*= require flat-ui
```

Comment: That was indeed the issue. I have no point of reference for these errors. Where can I locate the correct name to use, other than just finding it somewhere online?

Comment: You can usually find installation instructions at the gems' Github page. That what I did in this case. https://github.com/pkurek/flatui-rails